# How to reapply rescaling when you want to predict your data

Tags: predictive-modeling, feature-scaling

I used Data Science Studio (Dataiku) to create a Decision Tree model. Then I took the pickle file and loaded into Python to continue using it.

```
import pickle

f = open('clf.pkl', 'rb')
loaded_model = pickle.load(f, encoding='latin1')
```

On model settings, I used `standard rescaling` which uses the `avgstd`. Dataiku also exports this `json` file with details about the rescaling:

```
{
    "shifts": [
        4.2708957215287455, 
        5.582300530732055, 
        4.721780769116731, 
        6.309030531691733, 
        4.534705132386515, 
        50183.866161634876, 
        4.628957297141036, 
        5.931597829632046, 
        1.834355009673187, 
        21814.135528393213, 
        0.9999925875959688, 
        0.23165941222883746, 
        -0.11146363232269413
    ], 
    "columns": [
        "col1", 
        "col2", 
        "col3", 
        "col4", 
        "col5", 
        "col6", 
        "col7", 
        "col8", 
        "col9", 
        "col10", 
        "col11", 
        "col12", 
        "col13"
    ], 
    "inv_scales": [
        0.29041217789420476, 
        0.32026605114154144, 
        0.3398879256267485, 
        0.2539738260220278, 
        0.27817344479641604, 
        1.1217850173179438e-05, 
        0.3181917203503525, 
        0.2886476076886483, 
        0.37842451508835384, 
        2.329233011164756e-05, 
        0.21830904186227362, 
        2.003574563132119, 
        1.386943696546877
    ]
}
```

Let's say I have a new input with the original values (before rescaling). How can I use the above information to rescale all the features on the new object I have to predict the results?

Comment: Not having access to DSS, the data produced is unfamiliar.  One assumes that you will need to add (maybe subtract) the `shifts` and then multiple (maybe divide) the `inv_scales`.  If we knew the columnar mean and stddev of the training data we could likely figure out which it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding to jrouquie's answer, the formula would be:

For each column,

```
rescaled_feature = (input_feature - shift)  * inv_scale
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that the approach is brittle as DSS makes no guarantee about the data format in the pickle. But as long as you don't upgrade it, you should be fine.

Have you tried the "export to python notebook" feature in the model page? This one is meant to be readable and could help you.

Answer (score 0):

In neural network We use scaling  (max-min)+min

a<-(max(s$Cvs)-min(s$Cvs))+min(s$Cvs)